# How do you delete an element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript object:

```
x = document.getElementById("region-footer-first").getElementsByClassName("block-title")[0];
```

How do you delete x from the DOM?

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild

Comment: -1. You could have googled it.

Comment: i did and my keywords were not correct. stackoverflow is here for a reason. To ask questions no matter how noobish it might seem to you because your apparently a genius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access the parent node and tell it to remove its child.

```
x.parentNode.removeChild(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Modern browsers support the [DOM 4 `.remove()` method](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-childnode-remove).

```
x.remove();
```

---

You can shim it in older browsers, though not IE6/7.

```
(window.Element || window.HTMLElement).prototype.remove = function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};
```

Answer (score -2):

I think removeChild() is what you're looking for.
check W3C doc: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_removechild.asp

Comment: @bjb568 w3cschool is not the the the official w3c standard doc, but it's nothing inappropriate to refer to, open to any argument

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com "Members of the W3C have asked W3Schools to explicitly disavow any connection in the past, and they have refused to do so." and "W3Schools.com is slow to update material on its site, and provides no mechanism to allow the community to contribute updates or corrections. In a world where the html5 spec—itself built by a community effort—is growing and gaining speed, outdated and unchanging examples with high visibility are a hinderance to the web."

Comment: Thanks for the article, I don't minding saying that I still got to learn a lot of css and javascript from WCSchool, it's up to you to verify what you learn not by just taking what it teaches. As to be more consistent with this question specifically, it's correct out there. And of course, OP should test out to verify it.

Comment: Yeah, of course it's fine if you know the hazards, but it isn't the best idea to show it to others, especially without a warning. Anyway, you're supposed to include more than just a sentence and a link in your answer. The link can become dead.